# IMPALA - Complex Type - How to check if field contain empty array

Tags: sql, arrays, impala

As mentioned above, for example, we have a table

```
ID  content 
1    []
2    []
3    [{"name":"Jack", "age":18, "title": "MR"}]
...   ...
```

How to get all the rows that content column has value.

```
select * from t, t.content where t.content is not null
```

the above code does not work for the arraylist. Can anyone give any advices?

Comment: Does `where count(t.content) = 0` work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not work in both IMPALA and HIVE.